# How to change hinges values for geom_boxplot() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a number of figures, each containing several box plots in two facets, using ggplot2 in R, something like

```
p <- ggplot(tab_data, aes_string(x = "Group", y = var_name, color = "Group")) +
   geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
   geom_point(position = position_jitter(0.2), alpha = 0.5) +
   facet_grid(. ~ Position);
```

However, I noticed that for some variables, the box plot hinges are not the same as the 1st and 3rd quartiles computed by the SPSS, which the plots have to match. A bit of googling revealed that it probably is due to a default `type` used by `quantile()` (`7` but I want `6`). The type is changed easily when using `quantile()` directly but I have no idea how to pass the type to `geom_boxplot()`.

So, any ideas (suitable for an R and ggplot beginner) how to tell `geom_boxplot()` to make hinges the way I want them in a number of plots produced by a code like the one above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `geom_boxplot` or `stat_boxplot` does not allow to switch the type of algorithm used to compute the quantiles. But one option to fix that would be to use a custom function to do that, where I basically copied & pasted the code from `ggplot2::StatBoxplot$compute_group` but added a `type` argument to set the type of algorithm. This custom function could then be used in e.g. `stat_summary` to create a boxplot using the algorithm used by SPSS.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on mtcars:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Copy and paste from StatBoxplot$compute_group
my_stat_boxplot <- function(x, type = 7, coef = 1.5) {
  qs <- c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)
  stats <- as.numeric(stats::quantile(x, qs, type = type))
  names(stats) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  iqr <- diff(stats[c(2, 4)])
  outliers <- x < (stats[2] - coef * iqr) | x > (stats[4] + coef * iqr)
  if (any(outliers)) {
    stats[c(1, 5)] <- range(c(stats[2:4], x[!outliers]),
      na.rm = TRUE
    )
  }
  stats
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = my_stat_boxplot, geom = "boxplot",
    fun.args = list(type = 6), width = .75
  ) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(0.2), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]